# ssh not offering public key

Tags: windows, ssh

Trying to ssh on windows server using a public key authentication, but it is not recognizing the public key.

Kept the public key in .ssh/authorized_keys with proper permission.

When running in verbose mode getting below message:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\Users\$amku001\.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\Users\$amku001\.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\Users\$amku001\.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\Users\$amku001\.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
```

As can be seen it is not even offering the public RSA key.
Also it is trying for private keys which doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you didn't place the private key in your machine running the client-ssh.

Please confirm that you perform all the below instructions.

**In order to perform ssh login using private/public key you should:**

- Create key pair (e.g. using instructions from [here](https://www.codeenigma.com/host/faq/how-do-i-create-ssh-public-key-windows-pc))

Client side:

- Create `.ssh` folder in your home dir
- Place the private key in `.ssh` folder

  - name it `id_rsa`

Server side:

- Create `.ssh` folder in your home dir
- add the content of the public key to file `.ssh/authorized_keys`

File permissions:

- private key should be accessed only to you
- public key might be read by others (but not write-able by others)
- `.ssh` folder should be accessed only by you

Comment: When keeping the private key, It is asking for passphrase even though I have create private key without passphrase

Comment: what is the result of running ssh with -vv ?

Comment: Received disconnect from 16.202.*.**: 2: Change of username or service not allowed: (asiapacific,ssh-connection) -> (asiapacific\$
amku0001,ssh-connection)
Disconnected from 16.202.*.**